# C# Generic List Property Set/Add behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I want to store a generic list in the viewstate in an ASP.NET user control, so I have the following code:

```
    protected List<MoodleCourse> MoodleCoursesCreated
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"] == null)
            {
                return new List<MoodleCourse>();
            }
            else
            {
                return (List<MoodleCourse>)ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"];
            }
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"] = value;
        }
    }
```

So to add an item to the list, I call `MoodleCoursesCreated.Add(new MoodleCourse);`

However it seems then I must do `MoodleCourseCreated = MoodleCourseCreated` to activate the setter so the list actually gets stored in the viewstate. I suspect there is a more elegant way to achieve this, does anyone have any suggestions? Cheers

Comment: First, this is going to bloat your viewstate to a ridiculous size. Second, you're going to need an `AddMoodleCourse` type method, as you will only have a `copy` of the `List` from the property.

Comment: @Marc: Unless I know otherwise, I would assume that Alastair has a good reason of storing this data in the view state. Or do you mean that a List data structure has a ridiculous overhead?

Comment: The list will only contain a handful of items, and I'm storing it in viewstate as it is used as a datasource for populating a list control on the page - basically it's a cumulative list of courses that have been created by the user. Not sure where else I would store this list to have it persisted across postback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling .Add() you never trigger the setter. I guess, you don't need setter at all. Instead, override Add() method or create your own AddMoodleCourse(MoodleCourse moodleCourse):

```
protected void AddMoodleCourse(MoodleCourse moodleCourse)
{
    var courses = ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"] as List<MoodleCourse>;
    if (courses == null)
    {
         courses = new List<MoodleCourse>();
         ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"] = courses;
    }
    courses.Add(moodleCourse);
}
```

and now call MoodleCoursesCreated.AddMoodleCourse(new MoodleCourse);

Comment: How will this persist the added course in the viewstate? I don't think it can?

Comment: OK I actually tested this and it works like a charm. But I don't understand why! I don't understand how this behaves differently from the setter as on the face of it they seem to do the same thing

Comment: @Alastair - `ViewState` is like a dictionary of objects that are serializable. When you modify its contents in your code, no serialization is happening at that point. It only gets serialised when the current request handling is all finished. So if you store a reference to a list in the `ViewState` you can continue to modify that list however you like. The final state of it will be serialized when the current request is over.

Comment: >> I don't understand how this behaves differently from the setter

Comment: Thanks @DanielEarwicker, that much makes sense however I'm still unclear as to why the Add method does not update the object in the viewstate when returned from the getter - it seems one must create a reference to the viewstate object and only Add operations on that reference will update the underlying object?

Comment: This is the only answer that works but it seems like there should be an easier way to return a direct reference to the object in the ViewState so that the `Add` actually works - can anyone shed any light on this? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
protected List<MoodleCourse> MoodleCoursesCreated
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"] = new List<MoodleCourse>();
        }
        return (List<MoodleCourse>)ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't that return a copy from view state?  I thought the stuff gets serialised.  If so, calling .Add on a copy won't update view state.

Comment: @Adam: Why should it return a copy? Both the ViewState and the reference returned by the property refer to the same List object in memory. When the ViewState gets serialized, the same object in memory is accessed. (I don't think that serialization happens right at the point of setting the ViewState, but please tell me so if you know otherwise.)

Comment: @Heinzi I'm not sure if it is serialized at the point of access either, that's why I commented.  However, as soon as it is serialized,  the copy behaviour I highlighted will come into play.

Comment: However this works it doesn't let me use `Add` to affect the underlying list unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a property if you want it to have side-effects in the getter. Instead just use a method like this:

```
protected List<MoodleCourse> GetMoodleCourses()
{
    List<MoodleCourse> list = (List<MoodleCourse>)ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"];
    if (list == null)
    {
        list = new List<MoodleCourse>();
        ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"] = list;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: How would I use this to add items to the list?

Comment: Doesn't it return a copy of the list that I would then have to put back into the viewstate? Cheers

Comment: You would called `Add` on the returned list.

Comment: So it returns a direct reference to the object in the viewstate that is affected by the Add method? I'll have to test it out, thanks

Comment: Just double checked this and calling `Add` on the returned list has no affect on the underlying object

Answer (score 1):

you should hold the same reference in the getter:

```
protected List<MoodleCourse> MoodleCoursesCreated
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"] == null)
            ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"] = new List<MoodleCourse>();
        return ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"] as List<MoodleCourse>;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["MoodleCoursesCreated"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, since the downvote has not been explained and the solution looks correct to me.

Comment: -1 from me I think (I'm too noob to vote down yet ;) ) - This appears to be functionally identical, just using the 'as' keyword instead of a (cast). I don't fully understand the subtleties of the differences between a cast and an 'as' but either way it doesn't seem to allow me to use the Add or Insert method to get the property to update with the added items.

Comment: @Alastair - there is a very important difference to your original code: when a new list is created it is stored in `ViewState`. In your getter, you just return the new list without storing it in `ViewState`.

Comment: I spotted that eventual and tried it out, unfortunately it still seemed to be unaffected by the Add method

Comment: Just double checked, and this definitely doesn't allow me to add items to the underlying list with `Add` or `Insert`